# css3 nav height does not change

Tags: html, css

made a menu like this:

```css
nav
{
  margin: 20px;
  background-color:pink;
  border: 2px solid black; 
}
nav a
{
  margin:10px;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:bold;
    background-color:red;
  border: solid 1px;
  background-color:black;
  color:Yellow;
  padding:10px 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
display:inline-block;

}
```

```html
<nav >
  <a href="/html/">HTML</a> 
  <a href="/css/">CSS</a>
  <a href="/js/">JavaScript</a> 
  <a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>
</nav>
```

The problem is no matter what I set the nav height, still it will display very narrow like 50px so menu items display outside of nav.

I am using google Chrome.

**Final verdict: OK I got a working solution but no idea why display:inline-block  for anchors fixed it.
Looks like setting margin for inline anchors did not have any effects.**

Comment: Can you add a http://jsfiddle.net example please?

Comment: done. http://jsfiddle.net/bfwsbzhk/

Comment: I don't understand the problem, but you are missing a semicolon where you define nav border: `border: 2px solid black`. You define nav height below it

Comment: i replaced the semicolon; Just run the code. you see menu items fall outside of nav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `display:inline-block;` to the `nav a` selector:

also, the `height` and `width` of the nav or unnecessary, as they are set automatically by its content

```css
nav
{
margin: 20px;
background-color:pink;
border: 2px solid black;
}
nav a
{
margin:10px;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold
background-color:red;
border: solid 1px;
background-color:black;
color:Yellow;
padding:10px 30px;
border-radius: 15px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav >
  <a href="/html/">HTML</a> 
  <a href="/css/">CSS</a>
  <a href="/js/">JavaScript</a> 
  <a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: "height and width of the nav or unnecessary, as they are set automatically by its content"  . Usefull info

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS is broken:

```
border: 2px solid black    /* you forgot the closing ; here */
height:150px;
```

Therefore the `height` rule on the next line is not being parsed, causing it to size to its inline content elements.

Comment: That's a wholly different issue. Put `display:inline-block` on the anchors to fix this part.

Comment: you are right. Can you please explain why previous code did not work?

Comment: <a> are by default inline. how setting inline-block fixes the top margin?